# How to set environment variables on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, environment-variables

Can anyone tell me how to set environment variables for Windows 8? I can't figure out how. I've tried following instructions for Windows 7, but they don't apply to Windows 8.

Comment: Nothing has changed in this regard in Windows 8.  What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Also, no one has asked this question on SO, or anywhere for that matter, so I figured I'd ask here so others can find an answer quickly. I've Googled the answer, and can't find one. If you don't know, that's fine, but you don't have to vote to close the question. I'm sure there are plenty of people who could use this info in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of **Community FAQ** [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) (similar to [this specific question for Win7](http://superuser.com/questions/163891/environment-variables-windows7)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some ways to get to System Properties:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, then click System
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, then type and click System
- Open the Start Menu, type System, click Settings on the right, then click System
- Open Control Panel, then click System
- Open Windows Explorer, right-click My Computer, then click Properties

Comment: Didn't know about `Windows` + `Break`. Awesome.