# How to add Octave CLI to the system PATH variable in Windows?

Tags: windows, octave

I installed Octave 4 (from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/)) which has both a GUI and a CLI.
However, Octave doesn't seem to be added to the `PATH` variable, so typing `octave` or `octave-cli` into the command line doesn't do anything.
Is there a way to fix that (without adding all the other executables in Octave's bin directory to `PATH` as well)?

I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I add Octave (CLI) to system path variable (Windows 10)?

> Is there a way to fix that (without adding all the other executables in Octave's bin directory to PATH as well).

You don't add .exe files to the `PATH`, you add directories.

So you should add `C:\Program Files\Octave\bin` (or whatever your installation is) to `PATH`.

See [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/949560) for instructions on how to modify envronment variables (like `PATH`).

Answer (score 1):

You could open a command window using a `Desktop` shortcut similar to

> %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Octave\MyCmd.bat"

In script `MyCmd.bat`, you can set the `PATH` to the *Octave* `bin` directory.
Only the directory has to be included in the `PATH`, not every bin file.