# Windows Explorer Bug? Why is Windows Explorer Search Box not recognizing the character “R” for a set of file names?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, search

So this is a case of curiosity more than anything.

I am in the process up loading images for a very large number of collegiate products from a certain vendor. Part of this process includes grabbing the style # and searching for it in the folder that contains all the images. For some reason, this doesn't work when I search for any of the products that end in "R". If I delete the R, the image will show up - and if I replace it with a lower case "r", the product will show up. Using an upper case "R" causes the search to fail again.

Since I know it is happening it isn't really a problem for me, but it is weird. I don't know much about how Windows Explorer handles fonts/characters, so I could begin to speculate what is causing this.

Incidentally, I get the same result if I try to search through the pop-up dialog when I go to upload the image, or if I actually navigate to the folder within Explorer. Either way, the filenames that end in "R" can't be found.

Comment: I cannot recreate this.  Please provide an example set of file names and your exact search term.

Comment: So I am adding a lot of collegiate products, and many of them are Oregon branded. Each of them ends in either OR1 or OR2, such as:

JMU1016OR1.jpg
JMU1016OR2.jpg

In this case, if I search for JMU1016OR, I get "No items match your search". If I delete the "R", I will get all the products that match JMU1016O*, including the two files referenced above. If I then add back "r" to the end of the search term (JMU1016Or) Explorer will return both JMU1016OR1.jpg and JMU1016OR2.jpg. If I then replace the "r" with "R", I get no matches.

It's very odd, and I can't imagine what is causing it.

Comment: Upon further investigation, the issue only arises when the file names contain a number, and as you mentioned only for the letter R.  Odd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a workaround, search using lowercase.

You may have stumbled upon a Windows Search bug.  Explorer appears to interpret the `OR` within the search term as the OR operator (even though it doesn't have spaces around it).

The same behavior also happens with `NOT` and `AND` in the search term.

> [Advanced tips for searching in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows)
>
> **Adding operators**
>
> One way to refine a search is to use the operators AND, OR, and NOT.
>   When you use these operators, you need to type them in all capital
>   letters.

Comment: That makes sense. I bet you are right - thanks for looking into it! I'll count this as mystery solved.