# Can't change environment variables in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

In windows 10 whether I go to the control panel or through the start panel, nothing happen when I click to edit the environment variables.

[image]

Nothing happens.  No window opens.  The variables I have set in windows 8 before upgrading still work but I am unable to add any more which is a major problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/a/1002151) "Unfortunately, the recent update to Windows 10 (November update, version 1511) destroyed this functionality. The "Change my environment variables" link no longer works. It is there, but it is dead. So for the post-November version of Windows 10 the correct answer is: it is generally impossible to edit user-specific environment variables in version 1511 of Windows 10 from regular Users accounts. (cont)

Comment: (cont) For the time being one workaround for non-administrative accounts is to, well, add your user account to Administrators group, logout, log back in, edit the variables using "System" -> “Advanced system settings” method, and then take away administrative rights again"

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!  What the hell is Microsoft doing with these updates?  I keep having to re-install my motherboard drivers after each major update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Nothing happen when I click to edit the environment variables.

> Unfortunately, the recent update to Windows 10 (November update, version 1511) destroyed this functionality. The "Change my environment variables" link no longer works. It is there, but it is dead.
>
> So for the post-November version of Windows 10 the correct answer is: **it is generally impossible to edit user-specific environment variables in version 1511 of Windows 10 from regular Users accounts**.

**Workaround**:

> For the time being one workaround for non-administrative accounts is to:
>
> - add your user account to Administrators group,
> - logout,
> - log back in,
> - edit the variables using "System" -> “Advanced system settings” method, and then
> - take away administrative rights again

Source [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/1002151/337631) by [AnT](https://superuser.com/users/19097/ant)

Comment: The version with the `rundll32` command will work even when administrative access is denied by group policy.

Answer (score 5):

Use Powershell to set an existing environment variable like this:

```
$Env:Path = $Env:Path + ";C:\Temp"
```

The following command from Windows Search or Powershell will open the GUI for this on versions of Windows 10 where this bug is fixed:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

**References**

- [about_Environment_Variables | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6)
- [Tip of the Day: Using environment variables with Windows PowerShell – Tip of the Day](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tip_of_the_day/2014/05/14/tip-of-the-day-using-environment-variables-with-windows-powershell/)
- [How to run Control Panel tools by typing a command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/192806/how-to-run-control-panel-tools-by-typing-a-command)
- [Edit Environment Variables of Standard User Account - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/edit-environment-variables-of-standard-user/788f9195-1900-4553-ab84-bbc8eb3dce4f)
- [Executing Control Panel Items | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/executing-control-panel-items)

Comment: The rundll32 command is the only way to set user environment variables when the front door is closed via group policy

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 version 1607 the environment variable PATH is updated when you enter the full path to a command within the Windows Power Shell.  After the first time a command is used the PATH is update.

Answer (score 0):

start, search: powershell
right click: open as administrator
enter this command:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "EnableLUA" -Value "0"

press: enter
restart pc
Now you can edit enviroment variables in down position.

This message is from 10.12. 2018 :-)