# Failed to compile with make command

Tags: linux, cygwin, make, makefile

I'm working on cygwin. Most Unix commands work just fine. Also I can compile with g++ and gcc, but I get the error below when I execute make:

```
/cygdrive/b/tpm/src
$ make -f makefile.mak
"c:/program files/mingw/bin/gcc.exe" -Wall -Wnested-externs -ggdb -O0 -c - 
DTPM_WINDOWS -I"c:/program files/MinGW/include" -I"c:/program 
files/openssl/include" -I../utils -I. -DNO_BIT_FIELD_STRUCTURES AlgorithmCap.c -o AlgorithmCap.o
make: *** [makefile.mak:85: AlgorithmCap.o] Error 1
```

Note that I have the make package downloaded and added the bin to the path.

Comment: C:\cygwin , the makefile.mak , do you mean by its include option this ? (CRYPTO_SUBSYSTEM = openssl
include makefile-common)

Comment: `c:/program files/mingw/bin/gcc.exe` is not a cygwin compiler or cross compiler. Your are mixing cygwin make with a not cygwin compiler, and the does not work.

Comment: how do i fix it ? because i have installed both cygwin and mingw

Comment: @Biswapriyo line 85th    ` $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@ `

Comment: @Biswapriyo C :\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Window
s;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ ;c:/program files/mingw/bin, c:/programfiles/mingw/bin/gcc.exe;C:\gnuwin32\bin,C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin3\bin;C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe;C:\cygwin\bin;

Comment: appreciate your help mate

Answer (score 0):

The main error is shown in this line:

> $ make -f makefile.mak
>   "c:/program files/mingw/bin/gcc.exe" -Wall -Wnested-externs -ggdb -O0 -c -

This error shows that the cygwin `make` finds the C compiler path i.e. `$(CC)` in `C:\Program Files\mingw\bin\gcc.exe`. Here OP installed mingw and cygwin both in same machine. When the corresponding installer installs cygwin and mingw it adds the `/bin` folder in `%PATH%` system environment variable. Hence at compile time, the cygwin `make` grabs the first `gcc.exe` path which is in mingw directory and the error shows up.

To remove the path confusion, the `%PATH%` environment variable is to be configured properly. Find more details on how to edit environment variables in below links. Here I give a simple outline. Open Run dialog box with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Type `control.exe` in it and hit enter. Go to System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System Variables > Path.

[image: System_Variables]

Double click on the "Path" variable. You can see a window "Edit environment variable". Delete the two paths `C:\cygwin` and `C:\Program Files\mingw\bin` with <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

[image: Edit_Path_Variable]

Now make two batch files one cygwin.bat and mingw.bat. It can be done in one file, I just make it simple. Copy the following lines in those corresponding batch files. The commands will configure the environment to compile.

- For cygwin:

```cmd
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

- For mingw:

```cmd
@echo off
set PATH=C:\Program Files\mingw\bin;%PATH%
cmd /k
```

### Similar Q&A:

- [How to update system PATH variable permanently from cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219780/8928481)
- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/a/284351/726810)
- [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/949577/726810)

Comment: @bayern6 Oh, I missed something in mingw. BTW what environment are you using cygwin or mingw? Do you have mingw in 64 bit.

Comment: Not that. I mean with `make -f makefile.mak`. also try to make other projects like mintty in GitHub.

Comment: /cygdrive/b/tpm/src
$ make -f makefile.mak
"c:/program files/mingw/bin/gcc.exe" -Wall -Wnested-externs -ggdb -O0 -c -DTPM_WINDOWS -I"c:/program files/MinGW/include" -I"c:/program files/openssl/include" -I../utils -I. -DNO_BIT_FIELD_STRUCTURES AlgorithmCap.c -o AlgorithmCap.o
make: *** [makefile.mak:85: AlgorithmCap.o] Error 1

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EAI4ID3
path : C:\ProgramFiles\CommonFiles\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Comment: Scroll down the system variable section. Did you see any paths with "mingw"? If not then I'm out of any idea.

Comment: nope, no path with mingw :/