# How to start Skype from command line in windows 10 or start it at startup automatically?

Tags: skype-for-windows-10

I tried to run `Skype.exe` but it is not found. There is also no location properties on skype icon in start panel. I would like to trigger it after startup. In Skype settings i did not find this option.

[image: skype icon without location information]

[image: skype process can not open file location, because it is grayed]

I tried to run Skype from WindowsApp (I took ownership of the folder), but I am getting this error
[image: 3]

I realized that this Skype version is from Microsoft Store.

Comment: The path to Skype for Windows 10 should be something like this: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SkypeApp_<version>_<architecture e.g. x64>__<random string>`

Comment: The command line that works for me, after @ИльяАлексеевичЛевченко: `start skype:? Action = openapp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that. Either [by editing the Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) to add the location of Skype and then launch it by typing Skype.exe

or by adding a shortcut of Skype.exe on the Startup Folder. 
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that i dont know where is the Skype located ? I dont have it in Control Panel > Programs, neither in Program files folder :/

Comment: When you launch Skype, if you right click on its taskbar icon and then properties, you can find the location of Skype in the Target field. https://imgur.com/a/6Gps8Sy

Comment: Sonamor: but to create that shortcut i need to know the location.

Comment: I vs just told you how to find the location?!?

Comment: You dont understand, but i accept your answer as general solution.

Answer (score 3):

Becaue Skype is installed from Microsoft Store, i had to create shortcut from application folder

1. Win + R
2. shell:AppsFolder
3. Create shortcut to Skype
4. Do whatever we need. Put it into startup folder for example.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675

Answer (score 2):

I agree, everything is bad, I also encountered this situation.

I came out of it as follows:

1. I started searching for "skype"
2. At the very bottom of the search I found Skype without an address (located nowhere)
3. Launched it
4. I saw that this is something located WITHOUT ADDRESS, LAUNCHES skype
5. I copied this SOMETHING to the desktop, the functionality was preserved ...

Here is the address of what worked on January 7, 2020.
Put this in the "address" of the shortcut:

```
skype:? Action = openapp & source = skypebridge & caller = Double Click
```

Unfortunately, the same did not work with Telegram.
I'm now in search of a solution...

Answer (score 2):

To run Skype from the command line use the following command:

```
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
```

Alternative command (from [@peterchen's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1354182/how-to-start-skype-from-command-line-in-windows-10-or-start-it-at-startup-automa/#comment2341993_1354182)):

```
start skype:? Action = openapp
```

If you want to add Skype to the autostart, there is a simpler way:

1. Open Start menu and find Skype in the list of applications
2. Using mouse drag and drop the icon to the desktop. This will create a shortcut (`.lnk` file) for launching Skype.
3. Copy this file to the `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder

Comment: Thank you very much. But what does this syntax mean? I know the START command, but what about :? and the Action? Is there a list of possible actions?

Comment: @cskwg, sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

You should have the ability to select "Automatically Start Skype" from settings, in Skype. Click the ellipsis next to your name, and the settings window displays. Select 'General', and turn on "Automatically Start Skype":
[Skype_Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anMtt.jpg)

If you don't see this for some reason, I would create a task to start the program at startup:

1. Click the Windows icon, and in the search box/Cortana type "Task Scheduler"
2. In the header menu bar, click 'Action'> 'Create Task...'
3. Once the new windows displays, select "Run whether user is logged on or not", "Run with highest privileges", and provide a name (i.e. "Skype_on_startup")
4. Select the tab titled "Triggers", and select New
5. At the top, click the drop down next to "Begin the task", and select "At Startup"
6. Then select "Enabled" at the bottom, and finally the OK button
7. Select the tab titled "Actions", and select "New"
8. In the drop down box, next to "Action:", ensure "Start a Program" is selected
9. Next, click the "Browse" button, and navigate to where Skype is installed (i.e C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe)
10. Single Click "Skype.exe", and click "Open"
11. Once complete, click "OK" at the bottom. You may need to provide your credentials.

Alos, you will likely need to run "./Skype.exe", from it's location in Program Files (x86), in command line/power shell. I don't believe Skype logs it's path, so "Skype.exe" isn't really a command.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that i dont know where is the Skype located ?! I dont have it in Control Panel > Programs neither in Program files folder :/ About settings, i have total different skype settings window which dont have this option.

Answer (score -1):

Just Simple

Go To: C:\Users%Username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Skype.exe file are located

Comment: Skype.exe isn't located here.

Answer (score -2):

to open Skype from run is:

Windows + R

type lync

press enter or click OK

ta-da!!

Comment: Welcome to Super Use refer this link https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer will help you to compose a better text/answer.