# Windows Terminal with git-sdk autocomplete for git doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, command-line, terminal, autocomplete, git-bash

I am using git-sdk in my Windows Terminal. "profiles"/"list" entry for it looks like this:

```
{
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Git Bash",
    "tabTitle": "Git Bash",
    "commandline": "\"C:\\git-sdk-64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" -i -l",
    
    "useAcrylic": false,
    "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%",
    "closeOnExit" : true,
    "fontFace" : "Consolas",
    "historySize" : 9001,
    "snapOnInput" : true
}
```

I noticed that when I try to autocomplete git commands (like `git check^TAB`) it gets stuck and doesn't autocomplete anything. I have to `^C` it every time it gets stuck like this.

But when I run C:\git-sdk-64\git-bash.exe everything works fine.

I tried using `"\"C:\\git-sdk-64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" --login -i -l"`, because when I run `git-bash.exe` for a split second this line appears as window title: `/usr/bin/bash --login -i -i -l`. But it didn't work.

I tried using `"\"C:\\git-sdk-64\\usr\\bin\\git-cmd.exe\""` with various combinations of flags (`-i/-l/--login`), but `git-cmd.exe` doesn't seem to load my `.bashrc/.profile` and I sort of need them.

I also tried applying the fixes from this question - [Enabling auto-completion in git bash on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495152/enabling-auto-completion-in-git-bash-on-windows). But they didn't work in my case, probably because I use git-sdk instead of git-bash.

**EDIT1**: I tried using `"\"C:\\git-sdk-64\\git-bash.exe\"" -i -l` but this opens git-bash in a new window instead of a new tab of Windows Terminal, which isn't what I want.

Who else uses setup like this Win Terminal + git-sdk? Have you encountered this issue? How did you resolve it?

Maybe you know where to look for git-sdk documentation on bash.exe/git-bash.exe?

Answer (score 2):

To have this working as expected create a Windows environment variable called `MSYSTEM` and set it to your system type eg `MINGW64`

For a list of supported system types see `git-sdk-64\etc\msystem`

For how to set the environment variables in Windows 10 see here:
[How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

I'm unsure if this will cause any issues with other cygwin/mingw applications but was the best way I could find to set the variable before starting bash.exe

Comment: thanks, I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

> when I run C:\git-sdk-64\git-bash.exe everything works fine

Thus, you can to use `C:\git-sdk-64\git-bash.exe` instead of cryptic git-ism `"\"C:\\git-sdk-64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe\" -i -l"` in "commandline", isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately this opens git-bash in a new window instead of in a new tab of Windows Terminal, I tried.