# pip won't listen to PYTHONUSERBASE

Tags: python, environment-variables, path, pip, user-directory

For Python 3.8.10 under Windows 7, I changed [PYTHONUSERBASE](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE) from `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python` to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Python` by adding a `PYTHONUSERBASE` environment variable and checking the output of [`site.getuserbase()`](https://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.getuserbase):

```
C:\Users\Username>python
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> site.getuserbase()
'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages'
>>>
```

But `pip` won't listen and keeps storing to `Roaming`:

```
C:\>pip config set global.target C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Python38\Lib\site-packages
Writing to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
```

How to force `pip` and any other component that might still be looking in `Roaming` to only see `Local`?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

I think you didn't set the env var correctly！
I set, and it works fine!